# Will using setTimeout prevent the stack from growing?

Tags: javascript, performance, stack-overflow

Lets say I'm runnin some kind of long operation for a set of values.

The function that starts this operation is `startNext()`

and the very last line executed in it is to itself so its a recursive call like so:

```
function startNext(){
   var val = getNextValue()
   workOnValue(val)
      .then(doSomeMoreWork)
      .then(doMoreStuff)
      .then(moree)
      .then(startNext);
}
```

This will make the stack to grow as tail recursion does not work in JS (yet).
Will changing the last line to:

```
.then(function(){setTimeout(startNext, 0)});
```

Work better?
Will it not fill the stack beacuse it adds a new operation to the event loop ?

Comment: Did you check if it did? Did you try profiling your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `setTimeout` will prevent the stack from growing because the current function completes and the "recursive" call to itself gets placed on the event queue. It will also run slower because its not being directly called and instead processed via the queue.

To demonstrate and prove this try an experiment with Node.

Put the code sample below into a file and switch the `simple` flag towards the bottom. You will see that the `recurseSimple` function runs super fast and blows the stack very quickly. The `recurseTimeout` runs slower but will run forever.

```
function recurseSimple(count) {
// Count: 15269, error: bootstrap_node.js:392
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  try {
    if (count % 10000 === 0) {
      console.log('Running count:', count);
    }
    recurseSimple(count + 1);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Simple count: ${count}, error:`, e);
  }
}

function recurseTimeout(count) {
  // No stack exceeded
  try {
    if (count % 10000 === 0) {
      console.log('Running count:', count);
    }
    setTimeout(recurseTimeout.bind(null, count + 1), 0);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Timeout count: ${count}, error:`, e);
  }
}

const simple = false;

if (simple) {
  recurseSimple(0);
} else {
  recurseTimeout(0);
}
```

Exactly the same principal applies to promises. I didn't use promises here in order to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: That's an excellent answer and I think it must be so because how else could any long running user-processes be implemented on Node.js, say a file-watcher etc.

Comment: However it would be nice to know if this is because of the EcmaScript standard or just "happens to be" so. For instance can we trust the stack does not grow on all browsers ?

Answer (score 1):

`then` handlers are pushed out of the execution context stack, so it's already doing what you propose:

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code. [3.1].

This applies to A+ promises.

Here's the 3.1 note for clarity:

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a **fresh stack**. This can be implemented with either a **“macro-task”** mechanism such as **setTimeout** or **setImmediate**, or with a **“micro-task”** mechanism such as **MutationObserver** or **process.nextTick**. Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

[Promises A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)